# How can I make a pretty URL but still get data with PHP

Tags: php, url, get

I'm trying to make a dynamic page which will show the content based on the URL but I'm wondering if it's possible to make the URL more readable for the user.

So I have a page called work.php which will show a certain piece of work depending on the ID passed in the URL. So work.php?project=1 would show project 1.

Is there a way to achieve the the same effect using a URL more like www.website.com/work/projectname

Comment: Sure, but the question is into which concrete problem do you run writing the code for that?

Comment: thanks for the helpful answer @radu, all i was looking for was a keyword to research it further. mod_rewrite would have been perfect. but your answer was great too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

look at this: [.htaccess and mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) for apache

you can then process the url which stands in `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`

** addendum **

for example I am using something like this in the `.htacess` file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*
# Turn on the RewriteEngine
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
#  Rules
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php
```

So then I will always land on `index.php` where I will parse the URI and can use it as a distributer and router for my pages.

Answer (score 1):

You could look into how Apache Rewrites work if this is only for a particular script or two, which will then make it appear as www.website.com/work/projectname and on the backend act as if it were work.php?project=1

```
Here is an example:
# Turn on URL rewriting
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RedirectRule ^work.php?project=(.*) http://www.website.com/work/$1
```

If this is going to be for a project with a bunch of these pages, and you don't want to write a bunch of these rules, i suggest you look into a MVC framework such as Kohana, Yii, etc which take care of this as well as many other things for you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a file named .htaccess (nothing more, nothing less).
Place this file in the same folder as your other files for the website. You may have to turn on "show hidden files" in order to see the file when you have created it.

In .htaccess you can write this:

RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule ^work/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ work.php?product=$1

This code will give you work/1